# Distributed Caching in Hadoop File Not Found Exception

Tags: caching, dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed

It shows that it created cached files. But, when I go and look at the location the file is not present and when I am trying to read from my mapper it shows the File Not Found Exception.

This is the code that I am trying to run:

```
    JobConf conf2 = new JobConf(getConf(), CorpusCalculator.class);
    conf2.setJobName("CorpusCalculator2");

    //Distributed Caching of the file emitted by the reducer2 is done here
    conf2.addResource(new Path("/opt/hadoop1/conf/core-site.xml"));
    conf2.addResource(new Path("/opt/hadoop1/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

    //cacheFile(conf2, new Path(outputPathofReducer2));

    conf2.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    //conf2.setOutputKeyComparatorClass()

    conf2.setMapOutputKeyClass(FloatWritable.class);
    conf2.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);


    conf2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf2.setMapperClass(MapClass2.class);
    conf2.setReducerClass(Reduce2.class);



    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf2, new Path(inputPathForMapper1));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf2, new Path(outputPathofReducer3));

    DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path("/sunilFiles/M51.txt").toUri(),conf2);
    JobClient.runJob(conf
```

Logs:

```
13/04/27 04:43:40 INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating M51.txt in /tmp1/mapred/local/archive/-1731849462204707023_-2090562221_1263420527/localhost/sunilFiles-work-2204204368663038938 with rwxr-xr-x

13/04/27 04:43:40 INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Cached /sunilFiles/M51.txt as /tmp1/mapred/local/archive/-1731849462204707023_-2090562221_1263420527/localhost/sunilFiles/M51.txt

13/04/27 04:43:40 INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Cached /sunilFiles/M51.txt as /tmp1/mapred/local/archive/-1731849462204707023_-2090562221_1263420527/localhost/sunilFiles/M51.txt

13/04/27 04:43:40 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0003

13/04/27 04:43:40 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : o
org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@8c2df1

13/04/27 04:43:40 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1

13/04/27 04:43:40 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100

13/04/27 04:43:40 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720

13/04/27 04:43:40 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
```

inside `configure()`:

```
Exception reading DistribtuedCache: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp1/mapred/local/archive/-1731849462204707023_-2090562221_1263420527/localhost/sunilFiles/M51.txt (Is a directory)

Inside setup(): /tmp1/mapred/local/archive/-1731849462204707023_-2090562221_1263420527/localhost/sunilFiles/M51.txt

13/04/27 04:43:41 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0003
```

Please help me out, I have been searching solution for this for last 6 hours continuously and tomorrow I have an assignment submission. Thank you very much.

Comment: Which version of hadoop are you using?

Comment: Also share your full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using copyMerge() Property which merges all the files that are present in various machines into a single file and that file I was successfully able to use..if I am using normal file it is failing. thanks for your replies guys.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try -files option which is simpler.To be able to use it, driver class need to extend Configured and implement Tool.

Eg.,

> hadoop jar jarname.jar driverclass  -files file1.xml,file2.txt

In mapper or reducer:

```
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.xml"));
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));
```