# Files not stored in Distributed Cache

Tags: hadoop, distributed-cache

I am using DistributedCache. But there are no files in the cache after execution of code.
I have referred to other similar questions but the answers does not solve my issue.

Please find the code below:

```
   Configuration conf = new Configuration();
   Job job1 = new Job(conf, "distributed cache");
   Configuration conf1 = job1.getConfiguration();
   DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path("File").toUri(), conf1);
   System.out.println("distributed cache file "+DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf1));
```

This gives null..

The same thing when given inside mapper also gives null hence. Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Does the file `File` exist in HDFS? Also the final call to getLocalCacheFiles will not work in your driver code (but should for your mapper - i'm assume you are only showing this line as an example). Find your job's job.xml in the job tracker web UI and post back the value of `mapred.cache.files`

Comment: You might want to try -files option which is much simpler.See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251788/distributed-caching-in-hadoop-file-not-found-exception/16271657#16271657

Comment: Thanks for the info that getLocalCacheFiles will not work in driver, I was just trying to test. However in map class also, it gives null value. Now I just found that it works fine with DistributedCache.getCacheFiles(conf). 
Does that mean I can use getCacheFiles(conf) instead of getLocalCacheFiles(conf)?
Could you please tell me the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try getCacheFiles() instead of getLocalCacheFiles()

Comment: You have +1 from me, but can you please explain the difference between two?

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The whole point of distributed cache is to create local copies. getCacheFiles() returns the hdfs path of the original file. Downvoted

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is (at least partly) due to what Chris White wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12718643/1928660):

> *After you create your Job object, you need to pull back the
>   Configuration object as Job makes a copy of it, and configuring values
>   in conf2 after you create the job will have no effect on the job
>   iteself. Try this:*
>
> ```
> job = new Job(new Configuration());
> Configuration conf2 = job.getConfiguration();
> job.setJobName("Join with Cache");
> DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("hdfs://server:port/FilePath/part-r-00000"), conf2);
> ```

I guess if it still does not work, there is another problem somewhere, but that doesn't mean that Chris White's point is not correct.

Comment: Yes.. I have gone through these answers. I did not mean that the answers are not correct. I am still facing the issue even after trying these things. So requesting you to help incase there is any other point am missing out regarding DistributedCache

Answer (score 0):

When distributing, don't forget the local link name, preferably using a relative path:

> `URI` is of the form `hdfs://host:port/absolute-path#local-link-name`

When reading:

- if you don't use distributed cache possibilities, you are supposed to use HDFS's `FileSystem` to access the `hdfs://host:port/absolute-path`
- if you use the distributed cache, then you have to use standard Java file utilities to access the `local-link-name`

Answer (score 0):

The cache file needs to be in the Hadoop FileSystem. You can do this:
    void copyFileToHDFS(JobConf jobConf, String from, String to){

```
    try {
        FileSystem aFS = FileSystem.get(jobConf);
        aFS.copyFromLocalFile(false, true, new Path(
                from), new Path(to));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } 
}
```

Once the files are copied you can add them to the cache, like so:

```
    void fillCache(JobConf jobConf){
        Job job;
        copyFileToHDFS(jobConf, fromLocation, toLocation);
        job = Job.getInstance(jobConf);
        job.addCacheFile(new URI(toLocation));
        JobConf newJobConf = new JobConf(job.getConfiguration());
    }
```